# D3 Axis ticks by Week of Year

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 chart where I want the ticks to be by Week of Year

I would like to generate ticks like so Week 01 2016, Week 02 2016 etc

My data has only timestamps that are the beginning of the week for example 6 of Jan 2014 that is Week 01.

The problem is:

The D3 auto generation of ticks will generate a tick like 8 of January 2016 that If formatted will be Week 01 2016 but the data point is 6 of January 2016 and so
the point will appear before the tick with the same format and it will create confusion to my users.

Do I have to implement/override the tickValues so I have only ticks that are dates that are always the first day of the week or is there some option I can pass to D3 so the auto generation of ticks that this into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a d3 axis `timeAxis`, with a time scale, then you should be able to call

```
timeAxis.ticks(d3.time.week, 1)
```

which means "a tick every 1 week". d3 assumes Sunday is the beginning of the week, which might be just fine.

Alternatively, there's also something called "xdayOfTheYear" which I haven't tried before, but might work even better for you. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#counting)

```
timeAxis.ticks(d3.time.mondayOfYear)
```

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for. Awesome. Thank you