# SVG bar chart axis labeling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Looking to stylize a bar chart using a D3 SVG. Right now it contains a number on the y axis and, on the x axis, day by day labels. There is a tick mark for each day, where I want only the first date of the week displayed. How can I show just one a week? Code below:

```
d3.csv("us-counties-cases.csv", function(data) {

  filteredData = data.filter(function(row) {
        return row['county'] == 'New York City';
    });

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, width])
    .domain(filteredData.map(function(d) {
      return d.date; 
    }))
    .padding(0.2);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

  // Add Y axis
  var max = d3.max(filteredData, function(d) { return d.cases; });
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max * 1.2])
    .range([ height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Bars
  svg.selectAll("mybar")
    .data(filteredData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return x(d.date); 
        })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", "#b3b3b3")
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return height - y(0); 
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(0); 
      })

  // Animation
  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
      return y(d.cases); 
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) { 
      return height - y(d.cases); 
    })
    .delay(function(d,i){
        return(i*50)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [D3 Axis ticks by Week of Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705022/d3-axis-ticks-by-week-of-year)

Comment: Nope, axis.tick() method doesn't work if the scale you are using does not implement scale.ticks, as in the OP question, which is using scaleBand. Otherwise it would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use `axis.tick()` to set the arguments that controls how ticks are displayed. Among other things, you can set how many ticks to visualize.

However, as you can read in the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks), the effect of this method and its arguments depends on the axis’ scale type. If you are using `scaleBand`, `axis.tick()` has no effect and you should use `axis.tickValues` to set the tick values explicitly. Similarly, if you want to change the tick format, it's necessary to use `axis.tickFormat`.

For your specific case, the following code modifies the x axis to show only one tick every 7 days:

```
d3.axisBottom(x).tickValues(x.domain().filter( (d,i) => !(i % 7) ))
```